# Django queryset If statement never evaluates to true?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple update view.  That reads the POST request from a previous view.  This part works great.

```
owner = ADMirror.objects.get (employeentname=request.POST.get('userpost'))
```

I have a query set defined as:

```
currentlevel = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = 'owner.employeentname, active = 1).values('sr_datareduce_summary_code')
```

which the print looks like:

```
<QuerySet [{'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_c
ode': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_sum
mary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_dataredu
ce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_da
tareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {
'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z0712
6'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code': 'Z07126'}, {'sr_datareduce_summary_code':
'Z07126'}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

The query set will have duplicates for the sr_datareduce_summary_code because they are at individual program levels in the model.

I then have the following if statement to give a yes if true and no if false, but even though the queryset contains Z07126 my if statement never evaluates to true.  Why is this and how can I get it to work correctly?

```
if QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.employeentname, active = 1).values_list('sr_datareduce_summary_code') == "Z07126":
    appaccess = 'yes'
else:
    appaccess = 'no'

print(appaccess)
```

Comment: You're comparing a list to a string, that'll never be true

Comment: It looks like you're comparing a list of tuples (from `values_list()`) to a string.

Comment: How can I compare the values of the list to a string?

Comment: this is a values list, which means it contains many items, so which field would you want to compare to `Z07126`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryset = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname=owner.employeentname, active=1).values_list('sr_datareduce_summary_code', flat=True)

if queryset.exists() and str(queryset[0]) == "Z07126":
    appaccess = 'yes'
else:
    appaccess = 'no'

print(appaccess)
```

so `filter()`  basically return a `queryset` and not an object, it might also be blank, best way to check if queryset is empty or not is to use `exists()`
`values_list()` returns tuples when iterated over. Each tuple contains the value from the respective field passed into it.

If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. Example when you don't pass `flat=True`:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id').order_by('id')
[(1,), (2,), (3,), ...]
```

when you pass `flat=True`:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

I hope you get the idea for solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation Sumeet.  We'll thought out and you've made my problem clear as day.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a list to a string, that'll never be true

Either you just need to check if that code [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) in the filter

```
if QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.employeentname, active = 1, sr_datareduce_summary_code= "Z07126").exists():
```

or if you need to keep the `values_list`, assign it to a variable and use `in` with `values_list('sr_datareduce_summary_code', flat=True)`

```
if 'Z07126' in my_query_list:
```

Comment: This helps me out as well Sayse.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just loop the filtered Queryset:

```
for obj in QVReportAccess.objects.filter(
    ntname=owner.employeentname, 
    active=1, 
    sr_datareduce_summary_code="Z07126"):

    # do something with obj
    print(obj.sr_datareduce_summary_code)
```